# Orientation doesnt work when i add tabBarController in splitView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, ipad

In my app i have added tabBarController in split View's RootViewController.In that portrait mode works fine but it orientation doesn't change to landscape mode. Orientation doesn't change in landscape when i add tabBarController in rootViewController.

Please suggest me the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all your view controllers contained in the tab bar controller can be display in all orientations. see **Technical Q&A QA1688** for more informations. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine i forgot to put this method in one viewcontroller.